# Поиск по списку автомобителей

Tags: python

необходимо сделать поиск по списку автомобилей. Чтобы он находил как совпадение большой и маленькой буквы.

Audi A4,audi A5,AUDI a6 A7,BMW X5,VOLVO x60, audi a5

Тоесть из этого списка от должен найти все машины марки Ауди и выписать их.
Сделала такой код, но он не работает, где ошибка?

```
def search_by_make(all_cars: str) -> list:
 cars = all_cars.split(',')
 make = []
 for car in cars:
    if car.lower() in all_cars.lower():
        return make
    elif car.upper() in all_cars.upper():
        return make
```

верхняя часть спасибо, решена. По её принципу была сделана другая часть, но надо найти полное совпадение в данном коде:

```
def search_by_models(all_cars: str, the_models: str) -> list:
cars = all_cars.split(',')
models = []
for model in cars:
    if the_models.lower() in model.lower():
        models.append(model)
return models


print(search_by_models("Audi A4,Audi a4 2021,Audi A40", "A4"))
```

Код находит даже по частичному совпадению, что является ошибкой.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из основных ошибок:

1. В функцию не передается параметр, что именно искать (Audi) и не ищется.
2. Внутри цикла ищутся все марки автомобилей в начальном тексте `all_cars`
3. Не пополняется список `make`
4. Осуществляется выход из функции после первого же совпадения, всегда возвращая пустой список `make` (см. п.2)

Остальные ошибки можно найти сравнив код:

```
def search_by_make(all_cars: str, the_car: str) -> list:
    cars = all_cars.split(',')
    make = []
    for car in cars:
        if the_car.lower() in car.lower():
            make.append(car) # пополняем список
    return make

all_cars = 'Audi A4,audi A5,AUDI a6 A7,BMW X5,VOLVO x60, audi a5'
print(search_by_make(all_cars, 'AuDi'))
```

```
['Audi A4', 'audi A5', 'AUDI a6 A7', ' audi a5']
```

Можно написать код короче c тем же результатом, например:

```
all_cars = 'Audi A4,audi A5,AUDI a6 A7,BMW X5,VOLVO x60, audi a5'
print(list(filter(lambda x: 'audi' in x.lower(), all_cars.split(','))))
```

Comment: вопрос, зачем добавлять дополнительный параметр ввода в виде the_car?

Comment: Чтобы его искать. Иначе как указать функции, что найти надо все Ауди, а не, например, Вольво?

Comment: поняла, моя ошибка

Comment: AssertionError: assert ['Audi A4'] == [] 

может кто может помочь разобраться с данной ошибкой?

Comment: Инструкция `assert` генерирует исключение `AssertionError`, когда аргумент имеет значение `False` (ложь). Результатом вычисления выражения `['Audi A4'] == []` будет `False`, так как левый и правый списки не равны. Поэтому исключение и возникает. В каком месте кода у вас `assert` и для чего он?